# Kubectl patch adding extra "-" character

Tags: kubernetes, annotations, kubectl, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I'm trying to use kubectl patch to add an extra annotation to my k8s nginx ingress.

Here's the ingress that I start with:

```
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
  kind: Ingress
  metadata:
    annotations:
      field.cattle.io/publicEndpoints: '[{"stuff:false}]'
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx-external
    creationTimestamp: "2019-02-25T20:38:29Z"
    generation: 1
```

Here is my patch file that I'm applying `ingress_annotation.yaml`.

```
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      proxy_set_header l5d-dst-override $service_name.$namespace.svc.cluster.local:80;
      proxy_hide_header l5d-remote-ip;
      proxy_hide_header l5d-server-id;
```

I apply this patch by running `kubectl patch ingress kibana --patch "$(cat ingress_annotation.yaml)"`.

When I apply this it does add the annotation to the ingress looks like this when I run `kubectl get ingress <my_ingress> -o yaml`:

```
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
  kind: Ingress
  metadata:
    annotations:
      field.cattle.io/publicEndpoints: '[{"Stuff:false}]'
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx-external
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |-
        proxy_set_header l5d-dst-override $service_name.$namespace.svc.cluster.local:80;
        proxy_hide_header l5d-remote-ip;
        proxy_hide_header l5d-server-id;
    creationTimestamp: "2019-02-25T20:38:29Z"
    generation: 1
```

Note the extra `"-"` character after `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |`. I'm not sure where this character is coming from or what it's doing here. Can anyone shine some light on this for me, or how I can prevent this character from being added to my annotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [YAML syntax](https://lzone.de/cheat-sheet/YAML) that is probably added automatically by kubectl:

> **- indicator: remove extra newlines after block**

```
content: |-
   Arbitrary free text without newlines after it
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.